# How to get Search result Product collection outside result.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, catalogsearch

I need to get current product collection (actually I just need all Product IDS of products in current search result) of search result page in outside result.phtml, because I'm going to do something on layered navigation according to the product collection of search page can someone help me to get the product collection outside search result page

I have tried with

```
$term = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/query_collection')->setQueryFilter($term)->getData();
```

but can not seems a way to return product IDs from above code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind I found a solution and it got work

```
$term = Mage::helper('catalogsearch')->getQueryText();
    $query = Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/query')->setQueryText($term)->prepare();
    $fulltextResource = Mage::getResourceModel('catalogsearch/fulltext')->prepareResult(
        Mage::getModel('catalogsearch/fulltext'),
        $term,
        $query
    );

    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
    $collection->getSelect()->joinInner(
        array('search_result' => $collection->getTable('catalogsearch/result')),
        $collection->getConnection()->quoteInto(
            'search_result.product_id=e.entity_id AND search_result.query_id=?',
            $query->getId()
        ),
        array('relevance' => 'relevance')
    );

    $productIds = array();
    $productIds = $collection->getAllIds(); // as per Amit Bera s' comment
Zend_Debug::dump($productIds);
```

Comment: Chamal Chamikara,instead of get product ids from loop,you need to use  `$collection->getAllIds()`better for  getting data fast

Comment: @AmitBera ah yes :) it worked well thanks