# Magento Search Results: Echo SKU list of products in header.phtml or head.phtml

Tags: magento-1, search, catalogsearch, search-terms

How can I echo the SKU list of the items in the search results page, but in the header of Magento? Currently using M1. I'm using the code below to echo the list of SKUs of a specific category page to the header, but I don't know how to get the list of SKUs in the search results page.

```
if (Mage::registry('current_category')) 
{

$category_id = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id);
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->setOrder('price', 'ASC')
    ->load();

$skuArray = array();
foreach ($products as $item) {
                        $skuArray[] = "\"" . $item->getSku() . "\"";
} 

echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getID();

echo implode( ', ', $skuArray);
```

I tried the solution in this link, but it doesn't seem to work:
[How to get Search result Product collection outside result.phtml](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73404/how-to-get-search-result-product-collection-outside-result-phtml)

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. :D

Comment: So what is the issue have you got an error showing when you try that solution mentioned in your question?

Comment: I got no result. Just blank actually. :D

Comment: Is this the sku or ID that you want?

Comment: I just need the SKU. :) I need something like this in my header or head.phtml: 
ListOfItemsinMagentoSearchResults = ["SKU1","SKU2", "SKU3"];

Comment: Ok i just put a bit of code like yours but based on the  loaded product collection in search see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place this code within header.phtml or head.phtml

```
if($listBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('search_result_list')) {
  $productCollection = $listBlock->getLoadedProductCollection();

  $skuArray = array();
  foreach ($productCollection as $item) {
     $skuArray[] = "\"" . $item->getSku() . "\"";
  } 

  echo 'ListOfItemsinMagentoSearchResults = [' . implode( ', ', $skuArray) .']';
}
```

Comment: You... are... a GENIUS! It works as I wanted. Thank you so much! :D

Comment: No worries! Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: You actually sorted it out. Hahaha! I actually tried the search_result_list block because I found it somewhere and it gets the number of results when using productCollection->getSize, so I tried getSku, but I forgot to include the productCollection in the foreach loop. That's why it didn't work Hahaha! Thanks again! :D

Comment: haha yeah i saw the same thing much simpler than that other solution in your question aswell

Comment: Yeah. The one I linked is too long. hahaha! I think this is the one that we saw: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/89223/how-to-get-search-result-count-in-head-phtml but you figured out how to make it work for SKUs. Haha! :D I wish I could give you more upvotes. :D Thanks again Harri! :)

Comment: Ha just give Abdul one too :) i did

Comment: I already did! :D hahaha! ^___^ So sooo happy. Spent hours figuring it out. :D I feel so dumb. hahaha!

Comment: Haha awesome so glad i can help! Sometimes its just so easy to miss something tho i do it loads and when you notice it's so obvious!

Comment: yeah... it's just right in front of you but you can't figure it out. Until you asked a question at stackoverflow. hahahaha! :D